# visual studio 2010 display mouse location on form designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, location, customization

Within visual Studio is there a way to display the location of a mouse with respect to the form you editing?

On the status bar it shows the size of the form you are working on.  is there a way to have it show where the mouse is instead?

Thanks

Comment: It is next to it on the left.  You'll have to drag a control sizing handle to make it change.

Comment: So this isn't quiet what I wanted, and I have come to the conclusion that visual studio doesn't.  The feature you are referring to only shows the size of the specific tool that you are adding to the form. I needed something from the top left point of the GUI, not the object I am adding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input given,  I have come to the conclusion that Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support this option.  They list the size of objects(as informed to me by Hans Passant comment), and it can show them the location of the object, but it can't show where your mouse is in respect to the main GUI you are working on.

You can move the object around and view the location of the object, but you can't just move your mouse around.

Thanks for your help